# What to Do About a Redundant Question That You Asked?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question a while back and it never really got answered to my satisfaction, but I realize that a huge part of that was my failure to ask it well.

So, recently, I posted a new question that was much better formed, and got some really good answers. What should be done about the old question?

If you want to take a look,

First, worse one,
[Mechanics that Express Character Personality and Moral Growth?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46765/mechanics-that-express-character-personality-and-moral-growth)

Second, better one,
[RPG With Character Moral Growth and Corruption?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48003/rpg-with-character-moral-growth-and-corruption)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave a comment on the old one linking to the new one and explaining that it's the "replacement" or "second edition" of it or something  like that. That links them together as related in the system, which will make the new one show up in the sidebar and searches more. The old one could be flagged to be closed I suppose, but nothing *really* has to be done with it. It'll fade into the back pages of the question list on its own.

Comment: People should not be asking redundant questions, and when they do we should close it the right way to prevent later accidental action (closing in favor of the previous one is what I'd automatically do if I ran across two questions that seemed to be the same).

Comment: Well, I think the issue is that the questions aren't really the SAME as much as they are very closely related. They are definitely slightly redundant for my specific problem/question, but they generated different answers and therefore can be useful to different people. I'm just trying to figure out how to mark the first one as "answered" if _I_ personally didn't take my answer from any of the answers on the first one..

Comment: @doctorw0rm You don't actually have to mark it answered, if none of them actually did help. Absent the green checkmark, questions are generally considered sorta-answered by their top-rated answer, but still have a subtle "maybe a new answer would be awesome" element—and that's OK.

Comment: Oh, okay. That's really good to know. I felt pressured to mark every question I asked as answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The old question should be marked as a duplicate of the new one. However you need a large amount of reputation to be able to do that.

The solution? "Flag" your own first question as a duplicate (requires 15 reputation). This should bring it to the attention of the users with a large amount of reputation.

Comment: If it's not clear it's a duplicate, though, they may be left separate. That will be OK, because it's possible they won't be duplicates, just two separate kinda-similar questions.

Comment: If they aren't duplicates, you should probably clean up the old one.

Comment: It's not necessarily clear that it's a duplicate, because I sort of try to ask two questions badly in the first one and then narrow it down to just one good question in the second one. 
They are very similar, but it's possible that they generate different enough answers that they will be helpful for different people.

Comment: Is deleting the old one an option if it's badly formed and got no valuable answers?

Comment: If it isn't a duplicate, nothing needs to happen at all necessarily. We can leave both as they are.

Comment: It looks like a kinda sorta duplicate to me, but that could be just because they're asked differently.

Comment: +1 flag as a duplicate and we'll close it against the better one.